# What is an efficient way to filter lists or Numpy arrays?

Tags: python, filtering

If I have a list, for example, with numerical or String based values, I want to be able to filter through data easily and pick out stuff as necessary.

The list I'm dealing with is a massive one, and I'll be running it through multiple filters as specified by certain user parameters.

For example, the list could be like `[(Object 1, attribute 1, attribute 2), () ... ()]` and one of the filters may be only return tuples where attribute 1 is either less than X, or greater than Y. In this case, the ENTIRE tuple would be returned, with all of its attributes.

I realize that there are built in lambda functions with filters, or filtering within the bracket notation itself, with the `for ... in ... if` syntax.

What is the most efficient way to do so, and is there anything within the Numpy Library which would be more useful?

Comment: Have you looked into [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#filter)?

Comment: For numpy arrays, you might be helped with [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

Comment: More practical examples with what you're trying to achieve would be useful here; this question is too broad.

Comment: `pandas` has a great set of tooling for these kinds of operations.